# Making a program use a shortcut instead of a folder

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, dropbox

I have a program that constantly generates some files in a folder that is inside its installation path and I can't change where it's created.

I want to move this folder to my Dropbox and make the program access it from there. I tried to create a shortcut with the exact same name of the folder where the old folder was that points to the Dropbox one, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to make this happen in Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, create a symbolic link or a directory junction. Look up mklink (requires administrative privileges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to @LPChip's comment from above, the `mklink` command you can use looks something like

```
mklink /d <root directory> <target directory>
```

In this case, you want your Dropbox folder to be the object of the target directory, and the folder where your program generates files automatically (and you can't change) to be the root directory. For more info, you can refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink%20Microsoft%20Docs).